# Why do my files not match a Django 1.8 installation even though Bash confirms I have one installed?

Tags: django, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

I set up the virtual environment variable for Django 1.8 as per the instructions in the Django tutorial (1.8) and the (almost) matching 1.7 tutorial on PythonAnywhere. When I go into Bash and follow the instructions to check the Django version it confirms that I have version 1.8. installed.

I am up to part 3 in the Django tutorial at this URL:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/

In mysite/urls.py the tutorial tells me to write this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

However, when I actually opened the file I was presented with this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The tutorial then has this to say:

> Doesn’t match what you see? If you’re seeing admin.autodiscover()
>   before the definition of urlpatterns, you’re probably using a version
>   of Django that doesn’t match this tutorial version. You’ll want to
>   either switch to the older tutorial or the newer Django version.

As I said though, Bash confirms that I Do have Django 1.8 installed. What am I missing here? Why do I not have the correct files for Django 1.8 even though that's what I supposedly installed?

I tried to make the files match the tutorial files, but it only resulted in an error appearing on my public site.

Comment: What does `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV` say? If it doesn't say anything (emptyline) you didn't activate the virtualenv properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you didn't activate the virtualenv when you ran `startproject`, so you got the default Django from PythonAnywhere instead of the one that you installed.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that is correct. I will try a new installation tomorrow.

Comment: You were correct. I was confused about order during the initial steps due to swapping between the the two tutorial pages (Django official and PythonAnywhere supplemental). This was my first Django installation, so I was on a steep learning curve.